# Two possible responses on the same endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, response-entity

My application has an aspect that checks if the request is duplicated within a TTL and returns the endpoint result or a message.

This is my controller

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/results/shares")
class MyController(
    private val myService: MyService,
) {

    private val responseHeaders = HttpHeaders().apply {
        contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF
        set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fatura.pdf")
    }

    @LogProfiler
    @LogInfo(logParameters = true)
    @CacheMessageResponse(ttl = 60, false)
    @PostMapping("/email/{invoiceId}")
    fun sendByEmail(
        @RequestHeader("clientId") clientId: String,
        @PathVariable id: String,
    ): EmaileResponse =
        myService.sendInvoiceByEmail(id, clientId).toEmailCompleteResponse()

   
    @CacheRequest(ttl = 60, false)
    @GetMapping("/file/{id}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE])
    fun sendFile(
        @RequestHeader("clientId") clientId: String,
        @PathVariable Id: String,
    ): ResponseEntity<Resource> =
        ResponseEntity(myService.retrieveFile(id, clientId), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Inside the aspect I do a check and if it is in TTL I throw an exception, otherwise the endpoint calls the service and continues the process normally

```
    if (cachedValue != null) {
            throw DuplicateRequestOnTtlException("Duplicate Error")
        }


class DuplicateRequestOnTtlException(message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

In my Controller exception handler I handle exceptions

```
@ExceptionHandler(DuplicateRequestOnTtlException::class)
@ResponseBody
fun handleDuplicateRequestOnTtlException(e: DuplicateRequestOnTtlException): ResponseEntity<DuplicateRequestOnTtlErrorResponse> {
    val errorResponse = DuplicateRequestOnTtlErrorResponse(properties.download.message)
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS).body(errorResponse)
}


data class DuplicateRequestOnTtlErrorResponse(val message: String)
```

Everything works as expected for the sendByEmail endpoint, it returns ResponseEntity when necessary, however, with the sendFile endpoint this does not happen, When it is inside the ttl and is to respond to a DuplicateRequestOnTtlErrorResponse gives:
Spring cannot handle the response
an org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation is thrown and I can't deal with it because I get an Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler in advice

Comment: i  noticed that  you define the sendFile response type as APPLICATION_PDF,and the aspect of  sendfile and sendByemail implementation  is different ,  according to  your sample  error stack (it should be  demonstrate more about it ,  the whole would imporve ensure issue cause) ,it may be http  convert error ,  the sendfile  contenttype is APPLICATION_PDF , but you return   application/json in  globalException Handler  , maybe some conflict  within it ?  well ,it also may be that   you missed pdf message http converter ?